# Duplicated http request in ionic 2 with async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

I am new to ionic 2. I am using ionic v3.6.1.

Notice that the http request is fire x times, where x is the request bind to post with async pipe.
So, in this case, the http request is fired 3 times.

Kindly advise is this a best practice.

Provider:

```
  getPostById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.rootUrl}/${this.posts}/${id}`).map(res => res.json()).take(1);
  }
```

ts file:

```
post: Observable<Post>;
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.postId = this.navParams.get('postId');
    console.log(this.postId);
    this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId);
  }
```

html

```
{{ (post | async)?.id }}
{{ (post | async)?.title}}
{{ (post | async)?.content}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `share()` operator

Everytime you subscribe to a cold `Observable`, it is executed. One way to avoid this behavior is to make it hot. You can do this using the [`.share()`operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) (which is a shorthand for `.publish().refCount()`, for more informations about these operators see further) :

> Returns a new Observable that multicasts (shares) the original Observable. As long as there is at least one Subscriber this Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers have unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from the source Observable. Because the Observable is multicasting it makes the stream hot. This is an alias for `.publish().refCount()`.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.postId = this.navParams.get('postId');
    console.log(this.postId);
    this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId).share();
  }
```

### Quirks with conditions

If you use that `Observable` a first time in the template and then use it once again inside an element that is appended conditionally (`*ngIf`), you might experience some trouble as the observable would have been already run and no new data will get emitted.

For example :

**template :**

```
{{ (post | async)?.id }}
<div *ngIf="post|async">
    {{ (post | async)?.title}}
    {{ (post | async)?.content}}
</div>
```

**ts :**

```
post: Observable<Post>;
ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(()=>this.show=true, 5000);
    this.postId = this.navParams.get('postId');
    console.log(this.postId);
    this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId).share();
  }
```

Here the `share`operator (alone) is not sufficient because the post is emitted, so the ngIf condition becomes true but children async pipes subscribe to an Observable that has already emitted its value. Basically it renders something like this :

```
myPostID
<div></div>
```

There are two ways to workaround this situation :

1. `.publishReplay(n)` : this operator will replay the last `n`th items emitted by the Observable. We combine this operator with `refCount()` that will keep track of the number of subscriber and will reset the cold observable if there is no more subscriber.

   ```
   this.post = this.data.getPostById(this.postId).publishReplay(1).refCount();
   ```
2. Using `*ngIf="post |async as myPost"` This syntax was introduced with angular 4 (or maybe 4.1, I can't remember) it allows you to store the result of the pipe inside a local variable `myPost`. [explainations here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable). So you can keep the `.share()`part in your ts code and end up with such a template :

   ```
   {{ (post | async)?.id }}
   <div *ngIf="post|async as myPost">
       {{ myPost.title}}
       {{ myPost.content}}
   </div>
   ```

### 2 words about `publish()` and`refCount()`:

`publish()` transform a regular `Observable` to a `ConnectableObservable`. This kind of Observable start emitting data as soon as its `connect()` method is called (it makes the observable hot).

From [the docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/publish.md) :

> #### `Rx.Observable.prototype.publish([selector])`
>
> Returns an observable sequence that is the result of invoking the selector on a connectable observable sequence that shares a single subscription to the underlying sequence.

`refCount()` is a method that is available on `ConnectableObservable`, its role is to call the `connect()` method on the first subscribe. It will be called again if all subscribers unsubcribe and then another one asks for subscribing.

From [the docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md) :

> #### `ConnectableObservable.prototype.refCount()`
>
> Returns an observable sequence that stays connected to the source as long as there is at least one subscription to the observable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below pattern here:

*.ts*

```
post: Post;
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.postId = this.navParams.get('postId');
    console.log(this.postId);
    this.data.getPostById(this.postId).subscribe(data => {
        this.post= data;
    });

  }
```

Template is like:

*.html*

```
{{ post?.id }}
{{ post?.title}}
{{ post?.content}}
```

Comment: So is using subscribe more preferable than using async pipe in html ?

Comment: Now you have an issue no.Firstly try to solve that issue using above method. There are a lot of ways to do the same thing.No one can tell this is better than that and like that... So try above method and let us know about your result.

Comment: btw @Sampath `post`is not an `Observable<Post>` just a `Post`.

Comment: Yep, Corrected. Thanks, @n00dl3 :)